# Windows 7 Will not boot from SSD when other controller has RAID enabled

Tags: boot, raid

I have recently put together a new high-end gaming / work PC.

**The relevant hardware items for this problem are as follows:**

```
1 x ASUS Maximus IV Extreme-Z Intel motherboard
2 x Western Digital Caviar Black 1TB 6Gb/s 
1 x Western Digital Caviar Green 750GB 3Gb/s
1 x Crucial M4 256GB SSD (Win 7 Here)
1 x Intel Core i7-2600K Sandy Bridge 3.4GHz
```

I have the hard drives set up as follows:

**Marvel SATA controller:**

```
0->Western Digital Green
1->M4 SSD (Boot Disk With Windows 7)
```

**Intel Sata Controller:**

```
0->Black Drive (raid 0 member)
1->Black Drive (raid 0 member)
```

**The problem:**

If the Intel controller is set to RAID, Windows 7 will not boot (Even though Win 7 is on the other controller). I get a "Please insert proper boot item" error.

Before anyone asks, I ensured that the proper boot order was selected. My BIOS even allows me to select a device and immediately boot from that device - I still got the error when selecting the M4.

As soon as I change the Intel controller to AHCI mode, the system boots normally.

Does anyone know what's going on? I updated the motherboard and SATA drivers and still nothing.

Note: I forgot that my caviar black drives are 6Gb/s hence I would like to make use of all 4 of my 6.0Gb/s connections.

Comment: Why do you use the Marvel controller for the SSD? External controller never as fast as the chipset controller. My advice: Only use 6 SATA ports of the chipset and disable the Marvel - it's useless. There is no speed loss but a you gain much more less problems.

Comment: I have 8 SATA Drives. 
4 are 6gb/s and 4 are 3gb/s
Unfortunately 2 of the 6gb/s are from the Marvel Controller. I did not want to use the Marvel controller for raid so I put the SSD on there instead.

Comment: YOu have only one device where it makes a difference if you use SATA6Gb or not: The SSD. All other devices are so slow that it makes exactly no difference if you use SATA6Gb or not.